# Fibrations of $SU(4)$ and $SU(6)$

Tags: lie-groups, fiber-bundles, fibration

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69352/topology-of-su3) MathOverflow answer gives a fibration of $SU(3)$ as a $S^3$ bundle over $S^5$. Are there similar fibrations for $SU(4)$ and $SU(6)$? And could you suggest books/resources where I can read up more on this?

Comment: $SU(n+1)$ is an $SU(n)$-bundle over $S^{2n+1}$.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks, could you suggest where I can read more on it?

Comment: nLab has some related, rather (co)homological informations, for instance https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unitary+group , https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/special+unitary+group that may be of interest.